# What does the "High Alt Landing" guarded push button on the A320 exactly do?

Tags: aircraft-systems, airbus-a320, feature-identification, high-altitude

I am aware that not all variants of the A320 are equipped with the HIGH ALT LANDING guarded push button. I know that it is pushed before landing at high altitude airfields. Was wondering what it does exactly?

[image: photo]

Comment: Have you read [this facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/a320systems/posts/high-alt-landing-guarded-pushbutton-/2112841285504229/) that suggests it's about affecting passenger oxygen masks?

Comment: @MrR Interesting did not come across that. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The button raises the altitude at which the oxygen masks in the cabin automatically deploy. When landing at a high elevation airport, the masks might otherwise deploy during approach when the cabin pressure is reduced to the destination field pressure.

> **MASK MAN ON pb**
>
> The guard keeps this button in the AUTO position.
>
> AUTO: The mask doors open automatically, when the cabin altitude exceeds 14 000 ft, or 16 000 ft if the HI ALT LANDING pb-sw is set to ON.
> Pressed: The mask doors open.
>
> **HI ALT LANDING pb-sw**
>
> This pushbutton-switch changes the altitude threshold for the deployment of the passenger oxygen masks.
>
> OFF: The masks drop, if the cabin pressure exceeds 14 000 ft (+ 250, -750 ft).
> ON: The masks drop, if the cabin pressure exceeds 16 000 ft (+ 250, -750 ft).

<sup>(Airbus A320 FCOM - Oxygen - Fixed Oxygen System for Cabin - Controls and Indicators)</sup>

Comment: So this button would only be needed at La Paz, Bolivia and a handful of Chinese [airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest_airports) above 13,250ft?

Comment: @njuffa It isn't just the airport elevation. The approaches also have to be taken into account which are usually 2,000 feet above the surface.